# Magento - add event/observer to a new button in adminhtml

Tags: magento, button, adminhtml

I just created a new button in magento/sales/orders called "sync". What i want is when you click on the button it opens sync.php. What is my best approach to solve this issue?

```
class Module_Parcel_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order 
{
    public function  __construct() {

        $this->_addButton('testbutton', array(
            'label'     => Mage::helper('Sales')->__('Parcel Sync'),
            'onclick'   => 'setLocation(\'http://google.nl\')',
            'class'     => 'go'
        ), 0, 100, 'header', 'header');

        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

1. i want to add an button (already works)
2. onclick to launch a php file that does the sync (observer?)

**EDIT:** what im trying right now is to search how i can attach a event to a button so i can use the observer to trigger the sync.php, no succes so far.

Comment: Seams like you are doing it right. Maybe use `window.open` instead of `setLocation` to open in a different tab

Comment: The button works and if you click on it will go to google. I was hoping to find a way to attach a event to a button or some other way to trigger a observer.

Comment: You can link buttons to pages or you can do an ajax request on it. Basically you can add on the 'onclick' any javascript code you want

Comment: i tried direct acces to it and it says that i dont have permision .
(the link is correct)

'onclick'   => 'window.open(\'/app/code/local/Module/Parcel/Model/Observer.php\')',

Comment: You can do this by creating a controller in your custom module, and in the onclick of button you can put your custom route.

Comment: it doesn't work like that. In that file you have only a class defined. You should create an admin controller and an action and in that action instantiate your observer and call the method you need from that observer.

Comment: What is the fastest way to create a controller like that?

Comment: Check this blogpost by Alan Storm on how to create an admin controller: http://alanstorm.com/magento_admin_hello_world_revisited